# X509v3CertificateBuilder & JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder missing from Bouncy Castle 1.60

Tags: bouncycastle

I recently tried using JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder in one of my projects, but was unable to do so because the class was missing from the package. When I downloaded the jar from maven repo and looked through it, sure enough it was not there. Anybody know why? Should I fetch it from another repo? The documentation says it should be there under cert.

https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/cert/jcajce/JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder.html

Comment: Not enough details to answer your question. What jar? What repo? Why don't you just get the official jar from the bouncycastle website?

Comment: It's part of the `bcpkix-jdk15on` artifact. You probably had just the more common `bcprov-jdk15` included.

Answer (score 0):

To get the class via Maven: Try [bcprov-jdk15](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15), it's in there